# I want to get only numeric values greater than 10 from the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to get only numeric values greater than 10 from the table

```
select col1 from mytable

col1
----
5.78
14.5
14.67
12
10.10 VERIFIED 
15.3%
10
10.0
6.89
TNT
```

I would like to get these results:

```
col1
----
14.5
14.67
12
10.10
15.3
10
10.0
```

Comment: what is your dbms? also what is the datatype of the column?

Comment: SQL 2008r2, data type is varchar

Answer (score 2):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Col1 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable values
('5.78'),
('14.5'),
('14.67'),
('12'),
('10.10 VERIFIED'),
('15.3%'),
('10'),
('10.0'),
('6.89'),
('TNT')

Select Col1
      ,Value = Left(col1,patindex('%[0-9] %',replace(col1,'%',' ')+' '))
 From @YourTable 
 Where cast(Left(col1,patindex('%[0-9] %',replace(col1,'%',' ')+' ')) as money)>=10
```

Returns

```
Col1            Value
14.5            14.5
14.67           14.67
12              12
10.10 VERIFIED  10.10
15.3%           15.3
10              10
10.0            10.0
```

Comment: @user3376315 Happy to help

Comment: @user3376315 If this worked, feel free to select as the answer

Answer (score 0):

SQL:

```
Select col1 from mytable where ISNUMERIC(col1) = 1 and ROUND(col1, 0) >= 10
```

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '5.78' to data type int.

Answer (score 0):

SQL (assuming data type is a non-numeric type):

```
Select col1 
from mytable 
where col1 >= 10 
  and IsNumeric(col1) = 1
```